# noUiSlider control buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need a help with noUiSlider.
On the page we have multiple range sliders everyone must work correctly and output value on their fields.
This task was resolved, but control buttons what move by click range on the right or on the left doesn't work.
How to make working buttons for every range slider on the page?

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>time to call, сек.:</p>
                <div class="col-sm-10 range-wrapper">
                  <a href="#" class="btn pull-left range-down gray-color"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                  <div class="pull-left col-sm-7 range range-time" id="range-time"></div>
                  <a href="#" class="btn pull-right range-up gray-color"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="see ta-c">0.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>delay call <i class="fa fa-info-circle blue-color" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Information"></i></p>
                  <div class="col-sm-10 range-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="btn pull-left range-down gray-color"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                    <div class="pull-left col-sm-7 range range-time" ></div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn pull-right range-up gray-color"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="see ta-c">0</div>
              </div>
            </div>





var rangeTime = $('.range-time');
function createSlider (slide) {
    var slider = noUiSlider.create(sliders[slide], {
        start: 0,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        step: 1,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 30
        },
            format: {
              to: function ( value ) {
                return value;
              },
              from: function ( value ) {
                return value.replace(',', '');
              }
            }
    });

    // add the slider object to the slider element
    // using data for future reference
    $(sliders[slide]).data('slider', slider);


    slider.on('change', function( values, handle ) {
        // on change of the slider, find the next element and set its value
        $(event.target).closest('.range-time').parent('.range-wrapper').siblings('.see').text(values[handle] + ' сек.');
        console.log(event.target);
    });



    for (var i = 0 ; i < rangeTime.length; i++) {

    slider.on('change', function( values, handle ) {

            $('.range-down').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                rangeTime[handle].noUiSlider.set(i-1);
            });

            $('.range-up').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                rangeTime[handle].noUiSlider.set(i+1);
            });

        });

    }

}

var sliders = $('.range-time');
for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
    createSlider(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/35u6pas3/1/
But I can't to add this [link](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider)